# Python: copy file from a directory to another reading the layer columns

Tags: python, copy

I have a table with two columns with links to directory and/or file and NULL
Each record has a columns 'NAME' as name of new directory
Something like this

```
...  NAME   HOTLINK1                  HOTLINK2
...  name1  C:\...\directory1         C:\...\directory6\file
...  name2  C:\...\directory2         NULL
...  name3  C:\...\directory5\file    C:\...\directory
...  name4  NULL                      NULL
```

I'm trying to write a code to copy the entire contents of the directory (subdirectories included) and the file from HOTLINK1 and HOTLINK2 to new directory 'NAME'.

So:

- if HOTLINK is a directory >>> copy the entire contents of the directory (subdirectories included)
- if HOtLINK is a file >>> copy the file
- if is NULL >> pass.

Comment: Please try to work on the problem instead of asking us to write to code for you.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I changed the type of request. With last answer I'm writing some code.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a pretty clear method in human language, maybe just need a few tips to write them in Python codes.

1. How to read each row and the link columns, parsing strings by newlines and splitting by spaces should work.
2. How to tell if a path is a file or a directory (or at least exists)? Try `os.path` module.
3. How to copy file or folder? Try `shutil` module.
4. Watch out for the backslash in file path of Windows system, it needs to be escaped.

Comment: The human language is clear but I'm a Pyhton beginner :-). I try using 
logical reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
print(os.path.isdir("/home/el"))
```

result True or False

```
 print(os.path.exists("/home/el/myfile.txt"))
```

result True or False

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree('hotlink1', 'hotlink2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestions of @[Dev Jalla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5976205/dev-jalla) and  @[Neo X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5922657/neo-x) I have write this code that work.
It used the values of one column HOTLINK1. Now I don't know to add the code to produce the same thing with values of HOTLINK2 whereas the folder calle 'NAME' already exists:

```
import shutil
    import csv
    import os

    source='D:\\Prova_copy_pyhton\\'
    with open('D:\\Prova_copy_pyhton\\list.csv') as csvfile:
           reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
           for row in reader:

               a = row['hotlink1']
               fa= os.path.basename(a)
               out = row['name']

               if os.path.isdir(a):
                 shutil.copytree(a, os.path.join(source, out))

               elif os.path.exists(a):
                    try:
                       os.stat(os.path.join(source, out))
                    except:
                        os.mkdir(os.path.join(source, out))
                        shutil.copy(a, source+out+'\\'+fa)
```